# Python + MySQL: Search function returning all entries

Tags: python, mysql, search

I'm putting together an inventory program using Python and MySQL. I want to implement a search function that returns entries based on user input (programmed in a separate GUI file). In the code below, I expected that the search function would return entries with the brand "UGreen". Instead, it returns all of the entries in the table.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have used a similar structure in another program with a sqlite database instead and the search worked fine.

Any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import mysql.connector

equipdb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "REDACTED",
    database = "tel_inventory"
)

def view():
    cur = equipdb.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM equipment")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result

def search(name="", brand="", model="", consumables="", storage="", room="", photo=""):
    cur = equipdb.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE name=%s OR brand=%s OR model=%s OR consumables=%s OR storage=%s OR room=%s OR photo=%s", (name, brand, model, consumables, storage, room, photo))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result

#print(view())
print(search(brand="UGreen"))
```

Comment: You should probably dynamically generate your where clause (or use an ORM that does this for you) to include only those fields that you are actually searching on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using keyword argument directly

```
def search(**kwargs):
    cur = equipdb.cursor()
    key = str(list(kwargs.keys())[0])
    value = str(kwargs[key])
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE {} = "{}"'.format(key,value))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result
```

Comment: Well, that definitely did it! Thank you so much. Now I'm off to figure out why it works :D